# create pairs from sets

Tags: scala

If I have unknown number of Set[Int] (or List[Int]) as an input and want to combine 
i don't know size of input List[Int] for which I need to produce these tuples as a final result, what's the best way to achieve this? My code looks like below.

Comment: Since my answer refers to your removed code, I would have kept it there..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok. Since `combine(xs)` yields a `List[List[Any]]` and you have `a :: combine(xs)` you just insert `a` into the the List of all combinations. You want to combine `a` with each element of the possible combinations. That lead me to this solution.

You can also generalize it to `lists:List[List[T]]` because when you combine from `lists:List[List[Int]]` you will get a `List[List[Int]]`.

```
def combine[T](lists: List[List[T]]): List[List[T]] = lists match {
  case Nil => lists
  case x :: Nil => for(a <- x) yield List(a) //needed extra case because if comb(xs) is Nil in the for loop, it won't yield anything
  case x :: xs => {
    val comb = combine(xs) //since all further combinations are constant, you should keep it in a val
    for{
      a <- x
      b <- comb
    } yield a :: b
  }
}
```

Tests:

```
val first = List(7, 3, 1)
val second = List(2, 8)
val third = List("a","b")

combine(List(first, second)) 
//yields List(List(7, 2), List(7, 8), List(3, 2), List(3, 8), List(1, 2), List(1, 8))
combine(List(first, second, third))
//yields List(List(7, 2, a), List(7, 2, b), List(7, 8, a), List(7, 8, b), List(3, 2, a), List(3, 2, b), List(3, 8, a), List(3, 8, b), List(1, 2, a), List(1, 2, b), List(1, 8, a), List(1, 8, b))
```

I think you can also generalize this to work with other collections than List, but then you can't use pattern-match this easily and you have to work via iterators.